# How to find a DIP component implementing this simple logic?

Tags: digital-logic, components

I need to implement this logic in a very simple circuit. It will be perfect if I can use a single component in a DIP package, implementing the logic. How can I find one?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a 1-to-2 demultiplexer, where the lower input is the select line. You can use a [74HC237](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC237.pdf) 3-to-8 demultiplexer for this. (They don't make the smaller versions like 1-to-2 in DIL package).

Use A0 and A1 for inputs, and Y1 and Y3 for outputs. Make LE, E1 and A2 low, E2 high. Then you have the following truth table:

```
A1  A0    Y1  Y3

 0   0     0   0
 0   1     1   0
 1   0     0   0
 1   1     0   1
```

So A0 is your data input, A1 is the output selector: low selects Y1, high selects Y3.

You can use other input-output combinations for the same IC to achieve this, or for instance use Y0 and Y2 instead of Y1 and Y3 to get inverted outputs when selected. This is the full truth table from the datasheet:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can use 4 × NOR gates (basic 4001 or 7402) IC:

[image]

To get to this circuit from your's, replace each gate with it's NOR gate equivilent, then remove double inversions and combine duplicate signals.

It's often worth looking at both pure-nand and pure-nor implementations of a circuit to see if either of them fits into a small enough number of gates.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a dual 4:1 multiplexer, such as the CD4539. The two inputs of your circuit are connected to the select lines S0 and S1. For the first multiplexer, hardwire inputs I0, I1, and I2 to ground and hardwire I3 to Vdd. Thus, the output of the first MUX will be low unless S0=1 and S1=1, just like an AND gate. For the second multiplexer, hardwire the inputs so that I0, I1, and I3 are connected to
ground and I2 is connected to Vdd. Now when S1=1 and S0=1, and only in that case, you will get a 1 output from the second multiplexer.

Answer (score 1):

Not all 'random' circuits are available, but what you show is a 2-output (1-of-2) digital decoder-demultiplexer: Your upper input is the data in, the lower is the select, which determines to which output the data will be directed. the other output will stay at 0.

Such circuits are available, for instance 74LVC1G19, but that is SMD, and it inverts is outputs.

You could try to 'reduce' a 1-of-4 or 1-of-8 demultiplexer to a 1-of-2 by not using all but two outputs, but the jellybean versions of those chips (74138, 74155) invert their outputs.

---

StevenH beat me with a chip that does not invert. The HC version seems to be horribly expensive, but the HCT version is cheap.

Comment: The 1G19 isn't equivalent: it has OR gates, making the inactive output high instead of low.

Comment: S***t, you are right.

Comment: Wouter, your language!! :-) The [1G18](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74AUP1G18.pdf) is a solution. It's tri-state, so with pull-down/pull-up resistors you can choose the inactive level.

Comment: You are not supposed to be able to read what is under the *'s :)

Comment: Actually, ever since the invention of the PAL, all random logic expressions (of appropriate complexity) _have_ been available, in a DIP package.  Programmable logic is not a new idea - while today we think of BGA FPGA's and CPLD's that are at least surface mount, the idea goes back to the era when computers were made of boards of DIPs.  A PROM implementing a lookup table could be another solution.  Of course you and others rightly identified that this particular problem has an off-the-shelf solution which does not require customization.

Comment: I remember writing up truth tables and lookup tables to be burned into EPROMS. It's much easier these days doing that sort of thing in firmware, now that most products have a microcontroller.